# Quill - JSON > PHP > MYSQL - How to parse data from quill to php for processing?

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing, quill

Wizzards :)

I really want to use Quill richtext editor but I have no real knowledge of JSON or how is parses the so called "Deltas".

Basically, I need to collect the page from the editor and process it with php before storing it in the mysql database, and, from the database back to the editor if user wishes to update an existing post. It needs to be able to parse text and multiple images...

I don't have 3 months a piece to learn js/json, can anyone help me out with this one? Thank youuu!

So acording to the Quill documentation (https://quilljs.com/docs/api/) you can use var delta = quill.getContents(); to collect the data. Would it be something like this with an onclick() function? I dont even know with js if it has to be within a form? remember I don't know js :)

```
<script>
onclick(does this); // or can it be updated as the user creates the document?
var delta = quill.getContents();
// what then?
</script>";
```

The php would require a different variable if each image to be processed, perhaps in an array?

```
<?php

$images = array();

$images[0] = 'json/delta/quill image?';
$images[1] = 'etc...';
$images[2] = 'etc...';
$images[2] = 'wtf...';

?>
```

Why on earth they don't have a simple example of how to do this I don't know, its an all too common problem with these things.